# EPIC unable to detect PadWalker in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, eclipse-plugin, epic

I am using perl version 5.16.3. I have installed PadWalker using this:
`sudo apt-get install libpadwalker-perl`

After restarting eclipse when I started debugging I am still getting the error:

`Error displaying local variables`
`Install PadWalker & restart Eclipse or disable displaying of local variables`

Can anybody help?

Thanks,
Sumit

Comment: Are you able to use PadWalker from a regular Perl script? Try `perl -e "use PadWalker"`

Comment: Do you have more than one `perl` on your machine?

Comment: @HåkonHægland When I do `perl -e "use PadWalker" ` Then it is saying:
`Can't locate loadable object for module PadWalker in @INC (@INC` `contains: /home/demo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/site_perl` `/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/demo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/site_perl/5.16.3 /home/demo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/demo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/5.16.3 .) at -e line 1.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.`

Comment: @ikegami I have only one perl installed

Comment: @HåkonHægland If I do `dpkg -L libpadwalker-perl` it is saying: `/usr/lib/perl5
/usr/lib/perl5/PadWalker.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/auto
/usr/lib/perl5/auto/PadWalker
/usr/lib/perl5/auto/PadWalker/PadWalker.so
/usr/lib/perl5/auto/PadWalker/PadWalker.bs`

But my perl is in `/home/demo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3`

Comment: @Ajit OK then just install `PadWalker` with perlbrew's `cpanm` instead. If you do not have perlbrew's `cpanm` installed, you can run `perlbrew install-cpanm`. See https://perlbrew.pl/Perlbrew-and-Friends.html  for more information

Comment: @HåkonHægland After your suggestion I have installed using `cpanm PadWalker` . Now when I do `perl -e "use PadWalker"` nothing prints. When start to debug in Eclipse the previous error is gone but the local variables is not shoing in Variables tab

Answer (score 1):

You have two builds of Perl installed:

- `/usr/bin/perl` (the "system" `perl`)
- `/home/demo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/bin/perl`

`apt-get install libpadwalker-perl` installs the package for the system Perl.

I'm assuming you've configured `EPIC` to use the other, and this is the one that needs PadWalker. Run

```
perlbrew use 5.16.3
cpan PadWalker
```

or

```
/home/demo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/bin/cpan PadWalker
```